# Cannot log in to RDP

Tags: networking, windows-8, remote-desktop, remote

I have 2 IPs on my Windows Server 2012. 1st is local the 2nd is real public.

Whenever I try to login using RDP from a windows 8 from inside the network of the local IP, I can easily log in. However, whenever I try using the public IP, I get the below error.

The server is on a domain and I am specifying the domain name as such
NomainName\administrator

[image]

Things I have done till now:

1. added the ADMINISTRATOR account to the `Remote Desktop Users` built in group.
2. inside Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\System and under Remote Desktop Settings, the settings are turned on to allow remote connections.
3. The built in firewall is stopped (temporarily) to test if that is the issue.
4. The ANTIVIRUS KASPERSKY's firewall is stopped (temporarily) to test if that is the issue.

Any ideas?

Comment: is the machine a domain machine or non-domain? Eitherway you need to specify the machine name, backslash username

Example: If your machine name is TEST01 it would be TEST01\Administrator.

Comment: @doenoe I am, I just edited my question.

Comment: Are you using the same account when logging in from the local network??

Comment: @doenoe yes i am

Comment: Do you have RDP-NLA enabled on the remote machine that you're trying to connect to? If enabled, try disabling it, and reconnect to test.

Comment: Are you logging in from a machine joined to the same domain name? If yes, did you try .\user1 as the user? Also, did you try specifying the FQDN of that domain such that user = "marketing.contoso.com\user1" instead of just "marketing\user1"?